# Google Play updates the description and screenshots but not the app apk

Tags: android, google-play

I activated a new version of my application on Google Play approximately 3 hours ago. The information about it already been updated (description, screenshots) but the apk not yet, continue the old version. It is normal to happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure after you uploaded the APK, you 'activate' it. Just by uploading it, changing description and save it won't update the APK itself, you are just updating the description.

What I normally do is after uploading a new APK, I update the What's New section, go back to activate the APK and then finally hit 'Save' button.

Before Google Play, the APK update is almost instantaneous. But lately, new APK updates takes at least 1 to 4 hours to get updated on Google Play website.

- UPDATE: nevermind, saw you 'activated' a new version in the question.

Answer (score 1):

It will take more time to update the apk, generally I have seen anytime between 1-12 hrs, depending on the time of day you update the apk. Apk is updated once or twice a day. If you are lucky to update your apk just before the internal process updates then your will see it updated very soon.

Text and Picture on the other hand are just html that is rendered, so it is updated right away.

I try to update late night before or around 12 midnight, then by next morning 9am (london time), it is updated in google play / market.

Sometimes I have updated at 8am london time and it is reflected updated by around 10am!

HTH

Comment: I'm not sure about the Play Store app but I certainly think there was a bug in the previous Android Market app and it was nothing to do with the actual server-end. The reason I say this is last time I updated my apk, I checked with my phone (using Android Market app) and it still showed the old version sometime after the upload. My wife's phone (which didn't have the app installed on it) showed the updated version when I did a search for it. I found if I uninstall on my phone, then do a search, the update has appeared often within minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where my tester was able to see the production version of my app in Play Store but not the new Beta version update even though it was uploaded many hours before and available to other Beta testers as an update.

I had added him as a Beta tester to my Google Group, also added as a test user in my Google Play Store account. The solution was to force stop Play Store then restart it again.

The Beta Update was available as soon as he went back into the play store and searched for the app.